# QImage saving images to file names starting with p or j only

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt4, pyqt4, qimage

I am trying to save an image to a desired folder path.

If I save the image with the file name starting with other than 'p' or 'j', the image is not saved and no error is displayed.

code:

```
Image = QImage()
Image.load("C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Python\Images\zoozoo1.png")
Image.save("C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Images\pic.png","PNG",-1)
```

The above image will get saved correctly.

But if I save the image with the file name like 'aaa.png', it doesn't save.

ie:

```
Image.save("C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Images\aaa.png","PNG",-1)
```

Please suggest where I am missing anything.

Same is the case with file names starting with 'j'. Only 'j' and 'p' starting file names are successfully saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because Python is interpreting your backslashes as escape characters.

Try this:

```
Image.save(r"C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Images\aaa.png","PNG",-1)
```

or

```
Image.save("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Documents\\Images\\aaa.png","PNG",-1)
```

Comment: thanks it worked, but why didn't it create a problem in the 2nd step, i.e.; while loading the image to the QImage object?

Comment: Look for the list of escape sequences here https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals. Only some letters will result in a interpretation of an escape sequence. If this is correct, do you mind if you accept the answer?